# R console inside text editor

Tags: text-editor, r, sublime-text

What are some good text editors similar to Sublime Text 3 that can run an R console? Or is there an alternative of SublimeREPL that runs in Sublime? This is in Windows

- I have tried Rstudio but I don't like the interface, everything is too small and cramped.
- I like SublimeREPL but it's very unreliable and unstable.

Comment: "Good text editor" is very subjective. I've been using Emacs/ESS for nearly five years now and have a really hard time going back to `Rterm` or RStudio when helping somebody else. It is imperfect but *very* featureful and actively maintained. I've heard others claim functionality with `Vim` and R, though I've never tried it. (Not trying to start a war between emacs/vi ...)